# Heroku Application Error - Memory quota exceeded on deploy - Scout shows 4,804,423 allocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-management, webpack

I'm trying to find a memory bloat on my Rails application on Heroku.

I've read a bunch of articles about memory bloats and tried [Scout](https://scoutapp.com) to diagnose the problem.

I'm following [Christoffers question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146812/how-to-troubleshoot-memory-bloat-at-boot-for-rails-app) about Heroku rising memory, but i have a different problem. Mine is **almost always after a deploy**, then the memory usage rises and my app breaks.

Here's an example from the Heroku Metrics:
[image]

As you can see, the deploy is completed an then after the first visit the app is breaking.

I've benchmarked what i could(checked my queries) but nothing slow is showing in development. Also it doesn't seem that it's one controller, it's just **the first controller to be used after the deploy** that breaks. I've tried several, and they all break when they are first to load.

Scout Dashboard - Memory Allocation Breakdown is showing this as an example of a time out request for CategoriesController:

[image: Scout Dashboard - Memory Allocation Breakdown]

*The partial and layout are rendering as it should under the image*

---

#### System

I'm running Rails 5.1.4 with Webpacker installed and configured for Angular 2.
This means that i've added a Procfile in my root with:

`web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT` *this is recommended by [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)*

The app is deploying as it should with minor errors about `... has incorrect peer dependency ...`

---

#### Healthy and sick log

I've tried to locate a **healthy Heroku log** and a **sick Heroku log**.

Please request if this has any interest.

---

#### Number of workers

I've read the article [Ruby Memory Use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use) and tried to decrease the number of workers to 1 in my `config/puma.rb`, but with no result.

---

---

#### Updated!

1 . Weird behaviour with the memory usage on Heroku:

[image]

*It's starting after the daily restart around 100 MB but then after the timeout (first visit) the memory usage JUMPS to just beneath 500 MB.*

2. @grizzthedj mentioned the **public folder**. It is 27.1 MB because of the heavy [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) plugin.

---

I'm looking for help to locate this problem. What could this be? Do you have any idea - let my try it!

I've tried what i found possible and nothing has helped yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

You can find the app on my [Github page](https://github.com/peterhoejlundandersen/ExnerApp)

Comment: How many users are currently logged into your app on average? How are you deploying your app to Heroku(i.e. what framework)? Are all assets in your /public directory downloaded on initial page load? Are you using a cache buster on your assets in the /public directory?

Comment: Hey @grizzthedj - i'm using Ruby on Rails with Webpacker. 
**Public folder**  - yes they are - i haven't thought about the public folder at all. **No cache buster** either. Could that be it? I have a heavy [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) plugin i use.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few possibilities here.

First off, I suspect that there may be an issue with your webpacker build pipeline.

In your post, you mention that your `pdf.js` is 27.1 MB when deployed. When I download that file from the website, it is only ~514 KB.

I don't know what your webpacker build task is doing, but I suspect it may modifying this file unintentionally(via some wild card rule perhaps).

Secondly, there are also 3 other `.js` files in your `/public/packs/` directory that are 7+ MB each. Thats almost 50 MB of `.js` alone! There are also duplicate `pdf.js` files in your public folder:

```
/public/pdfjs/build/pdf.js
/public/pdf_categories/build/pdf.js
```

Hard to tell if these are the only issues, but for starters, I would do the following(if you are not doing already):

1. Double check that your webpacker is not adding any bloat to your
   pdf.js
2. Use webpacker to minify your `.js` and `.css` files
3. Ensure that you are using [gzip compression](https://coderwall.com/p/qxxueq/enable-gzip-support-on-heroku) for all static assets.

Comment: Thank you so much @grizztjhedj - i will try the three things and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

So... I want to share something:

I had another app - an old one - that had the same problem when deploying. **After each deploy the app would break** - Memory quota exceeded - and after a while it would be up and running again.

In the Heroku Logs is said, before the error:

`[Webpacker] Compiling…`

---

I figured out from a [Github Issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1126) that my `config/webpacker.yml` had a small difference from theirs.

In the bottom of the `webpacker.yml` there is the setting for the production and mine where:

`compiling: true`

This means

### that on the first load on a page using a webpacker file, for example a `javascript_pack_tack` in rails, the compiling would start, even when Webpacker already compiled the files on deployment

You can see it's done on a deploy to Heroku - after the assets:precompile:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
...
Done in 24.02s.
remote:        Webpacker is installed  
remote:        Using /tmp/build_../config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
remote:        Compiling…
```

My app wasn't using the compiled files from deployment - so the error was **that i compiled twice!!**. And the memory on a hobby plan on Heroku wasn't enough for the second one.

When i changed the settings to:

`compile: false`

It all worked as it should!

I hope it will help somebody.